# Why make file is not generated while installing mvapich2

Tags: 12.04

I am installing MVAPICH2 on my PC following the instructions [given here](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/support/mvapich2-2.0a-quick-start.html)

But after `./configure` I must have makefile. I did ls and found that no such file is there. Because of this make is not working.

What should I do to solve this issue?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

**Update**

```
root@ubuntu:/home# lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
01:07.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:301d]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
```

Based on the suggestions by Radu Rădeanu I tried:

```
./configure --with-device=ch3:sock
```

still no makefile is generating so my `make` is not working.

i can see a src folder, so when I go there I found one Makefile.mk. But even there make is not working. Says:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/acme/Downloads/mvapich2-2.0a/src# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your network adapter. From http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/support/mvapich2-2.0a-quick-start.html:

> If you’re using a Mellanox InfiniBand, RoCE, or iWARP network adapter you can use the default configuration…
>
> ```
> $ ./configure
> ```
>
> **If you’re using a QLogic InfiniBand adapter you should
>   use…**
>
> ```
> $ ./configure --with-device=ch3:psm
> ```

See also: http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/support/user_guide_mvapich2-2.0a.html#x1-50004

Comment: I am having normal LAN connection with Ethernet cards. what do I do? I dont see any option for normal ethernet.

Comment: @gpuguy Even a normal ethernet card have a name... Have you read/tried everything from here: http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/support/user_guide_mvapich2-2.0a.html#x1-50004?

Comment: typing lspci at terminal gives: '01:07.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)' now I am not able to understand out of the 5 adapters given in the doc which category this adapter   belong to.

Comment: @gpuguy What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` command?

Comment: its : 01:07.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:301d]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too

Comment: @gpuguy Then try with [4.11 Configuring a build for TCP/IP-CH3](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/support/user_guide_mvapich2-2.0a.html#x1-190004.11): `./configure --with-device=ch3:sock`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11157/discussion-between-gpuguy-and-radu-rdeanu)